# Identify the function call statement in the following snippet

Tags: python

[image]
I know that the main(sys.argv[1:]) is the function call statement but I have no idea about the other two variables and why it's used. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Coding questions are off-topic here.  Don't use images of text; that makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired.  Instead, transcribe all text.  Please credit the original source for this copied material.

Answer (score 2):

Are you writing an interview test right now ?

`__name__` is not a function. Is a special keyword used by Python and its value is `‘__main__’` if the script is run directly from terminal.
So if another script.py imports the one in the photo, the code inside the if statement won’t execute.

```
sys.argv
```

Is a list of the arguments of the script, if given any from the terminal. The reason of sys.argv[1:] is to exclude the first argument which is the file name of the script.

So you are right. The only function call statement is the `main(...)`

As far as for why the notorious

```
if __name__ == ‘__main__:’
```

is used, I would say for testing purposes. Imagine having a lot of .py files which import other .py files. You need to test each one separately from the other.

Comment: Nope. I'm currently studying 12th grade and this is one of our textbook questions.

Comment: Wow.. Thanks for the answer. That clears so much things.